# new Outlook.ItemEvents_10_ReplyEventHandler(MailItem_Reply) - no sender email details

Tags: c#, outlook-2010

I'm getting `null` for the `sender.name` and `SenderName` when trying to reply to an email

```
private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    currentExplorer = this.Application.ActiveExplorer();
    currentExplorer.SelectionChange += new Outlook.ExplorerEvents_10_SelectionChangeEventHandler(CurrentExplorer_Event);
}

private void CurrentExplorer_Event()
{
    if (this.Application.ActiveExplorer().Selection.Count == 1
     && this.Application.ActiveExplorer().Selection[1] is Outlook.MailItem)
    {
        if (mailItem != null)
        {
            ((Outlook.ItemEvents_10_Event)mailItem).Reply -= new Outlook.ItemEvents_10_ReplyEventHandler(MailItem_Reply);
        }

        mailItem = this.Application.ActiveExplorer().Selection[1];
        ((Outlook.ItemEvents_10_Event)mailItem).Reply += new
        Outlook.ItemEvents_10_ReplyEventHandler(MailItem_Reply);
    }
} 

void MailItem_Reply(Object response, ref bool cancel)
{
    Outlook.MailItem mailItem = (Outlook.MailItem)response;

    mailItem.GetInspector.Activate();
    string u = mailItem.Subject;
    string x = mailItem.Sender.Name;
    string r = mailItem.SenderName;

    mailItem.Body = "Hi " + x.Split(' ')[0]+ "\n" + mailItem .Body;
}
```

I also get

> Ambiguity between method 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook._Inspector.Activate()' and non-method 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.InspectorEvents_10_Event.Activate'. Using method group.

Can someone tell me how to correctly do this so I can reply automatically with e.g. the sender name and also remove this ambiguity?

Comment: MailItem is often not initialized when preparing a new email - I usually do `mail.Save();` to get properties initialized. Not sure about the ambiguity - you're casting for Reply already.

Comment: Just cast to `((Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook._Inspector)mailItem.GetInspector).Activate();` - it has an event under the same name in different interface. Let me know how it works out (with @...)

Comment: hey, did it help? If it did, let me know to post an answer so you can close/up the answer - you should always do that.

Answer (score 1):

*(based on our discussion as this seems to have helped)*

MailItem is often not initialized when preparing a new email...

> I usually do mail.Save(); to get properties initialized

For the cast problem...

> Just cast to
>   ((Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook._Inspector)mailItem.GetInspector).Activate()‌​;
>   - it has an event under the same name in different interface.